# in GTK, how do I get the original normal bg color of a widget?

Tags: python, gtk, colors, themes

I do this:

```
    self.origbg = self.style.bg[gtk.STATE_NORMAL]
```

and later in my eventboxes I change the bgcolor to it by doing:

```
    self.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, color)
```

However, the color actually *changes*! It's not the state_normal color that I get from looking at self.style.bg . On my Windows, it's a slightly lighter tint. How do I get the real background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the widget's "map-event" signal (which is sent when the widget is first shown in a window); this is the first time you can read the real theme colors.

Comment: this should be documented better

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid listening for map event you should call `realize()` and then get colors. I know this is an old issue but just wanted to contribute in case people run into it like I did. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get the default background color for an entry in GTK3

```
   context = entry.get_style_context()
   default_background = context.get_background_color(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL)
```